# Applescript to run Javascript with text inserted in prompt

Tags: javascript, url, safari, applescript, prompt

I use an Applescript to open a Javascript prompt for YubNub in Safari. Occasionally I use a search scope more often like "ebay" ect and I would like the Yubnub command already typed in the prompt so I can just type my search. I have tried the following script to type "ebay" in the prompt and it only shows an empty prompt.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

the script:

```
    tell application "Safari"
do JavaScript          
              "javascript:Qr=prompt('','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.yubnub.org/parser/parse?         command='+escape(Qr)" in current tab of first window
    end tell
     delay 0.3
    tell application "System Events" to key code 14
    tell application "System Events" to key code 11
    tell application "System Events" to key code 0
    tell application "System Events" to key code 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same issue as I described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227234/applescripting-down-arrow-to-highlight-and-select-file-within-a-photoshop-cs5/20260893#20260893). Basically when you open the prompt from applescript, the whole applescript pauses until you dismiss the prompt. Same as the other question. Read that to get the full explanation. As such you could do this...

```
set searchTerm to "ebay"

do shell script "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'delay 1' -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" & searchTerm & space & "\"' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set newTab to make new tab in window 1
    set current tab of window 1 to newTab
    do JavaScript "javascript:Qr=prompt('','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.yubnub.org/parser/parse?         command='+escape(Qr)" in current tab of first window
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: any chance you would know how to get the above script to open it in a new window. I have tried for a few hours with no success.

Comment: I added the code to create a new tab in the current window, so your search will occur in that. Good luck. Also, please mark my post as the answer to your question by checking it... if it does in fact answer your question.

Comment: Sure it's possible. The trick is it's not called a window. It's a document. In the script just replace the 2 lines about the tab with "make new document".

Comment: I replaced "the set newTab to make new tab in window 1
 set current tab of window 1 to newTab" with "make new document" and it just opens it in the same window.

Comment: Does a new window open? If so then you probably need to "delay 0.5" after you make the new document to give Safari time to actually open a new window.

Comment: It works great when not in full screen mode. In full screen, it jumps to the previous window and opens it there after I press "OK" on the prompt.

Comment: I figured it out. After replacing the last part with "thiswindow", everything works now.         set searchTerm to "ebay"

do shell script "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'delay 1.4' -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" & searchTerm & space & "\"' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

tell application "Safari"
 activate
 set thisWindow to make new document
 do JavaScript "javascript:Qr=prompt('','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.yubnub.org/parser/parse?command='+escape(Qr)" in thisWindow
end tell

Comment: Great. Glad you got what you wanted. Good luck.